# Inserting jQuery Validation Code into the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application, and I have the task to insert some HTML code (some form) and Javascript code (mostly jQuery validation for the inserted form) into the DOM of a web page - the HTML and the Javascript code are both returned via Ajax calls:

```
         var id = jQuery(this).attr("data-id");
         var querystring = "id=" + id;
         jQuery.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "Home/GetEditViewHTMLById",
             data: querystring,
             dataType: "html"
         }).done(function (msg_html) {
             jQuery.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "Home/GetEditViewJavascriptById",
                 data: querystring,
                 dataType: "script"
             }).done(function (msg_javascript) {
                 jQuery("#content").html(msg_html); // inserting the HTML

                 var script = document.createElement("script");
                 script.type = "text/javascript";
                 script.text = msg_javascript;
                 document.body.appendChild(script); // inserting the Javascript - doesn't work
                 Edit(); // <- this function would be in the inserted Javascript code
             });
         });
```

The "msg_javascript" variable contains the Javascript code, if I call alert, I can see the result of the Ajax call:

```
       function Edit(){
          jQuery("#plugin").validate( { errorElement: 'div' } );
          jQuery("#sum1").rules("add", { required: true, messages: { required: "!" }  });
          jQuery.validator.addMethod("regex_sum1",
                  function (value, element, regexp) {
                      var check = false;
                      var re = new RegExp(regexp);
                      return re.test(value);
                  },
                  "Wrong number format!");
          jQuery("#sum1").rules("add", { regex_sum1: "^[1-9][0-9]*$" });
          jQuery("#sum2").rules("add", { required: true, messages: { required: "!" }  });
          jQuery.validator.addMethod("regex_sum2",
                  function (value, element, regexp) {
                      var check = false;
                      var re = new RegExp(regexp);
                      return re.test(value);
                  },
                  "Wrong number format!");

          jQuery("#email").rules("add", { required: true, messages: { required: "!" }  });

          jQuery.validator.addMethod("regex_email",
                  function (value, element, regexp) {
                      var check = false;
                      var re = new RegExp(regexp);
                      return re.test(value);
                  },
                  "Wrong e-mail format!");
          jQuery("#email").rules("add", { regex_email: "^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$" });
          jQuery('input').blur(function(){
                          if(!jQuery(this).valid()){
                             return false;
                         }
                      });

          function calculate(){
               return (Number(jQuery('#sum1').val())*(Number(jQuery('#sum2').val())+0.5));
          }
          function getFields(){
               return ["sum1","sum2"];
          }
          function validateRange(value){
               return 1000 <= value && value <= 10000;
          }}
```

If I return the following function from server:

```
          function Edit(){ 
                alert("okay");
          }
```

- everything is okay, and the alert executes.
  If I return that Javascript function above, the function doesn't execute, and I can't see the script tag in the Firebug neither, so I don't really know how to debug this problem.
  What did I do wrong? Please, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't run in a returned variable, you must execute it:

```
eval(msg_javascript);
```

Comment: For me, the eval doesn't do anything. It's strange, because if I paste the Javascript code into a script tag in notepad, everything works fine.

Comment: Sometimes eval() chokes on otherwise valid Javascript. I've had to often simplify javascript to make it work in the eval(). That's the problem, though. Javascript doesn't automatically execute when you add it to an element from within javascript. I use the jQuery command $.getScript(), which will load a script dynamically, and then execute it.

Comment: Thanks! Finally I have found the problem, which was really obvious: I have not "included" the Javascript libraries, such as the Validation Plugin Javascript file before I eval'd the code. So I've debugged the eval code with a try-catch block, and finally have used the $.getScript method to load .js scripts.